# Break long string at specif char and max length (JS)

Tags: javascript

Probably there is an answser much cleaner and more working than mine, but i cannot find. So i did try for myself with not much result so far.

```js
var str = "Persons: Amy, bertha, Charlie, Donkey, Evy, Felicia, Ghunter, Hercules, Indica, Jody, Katy, Linsay, Moony, Nigel, Opethry, Phil, Quinton, Ricial, Stefany, Trudy, Ursla, Vlinder, Wendy, Xion, Yvy, Zulu"; // person name come from an Array()

var maxCount = 100;
var jki = Math.floor(str.length / maxCount);
var i = 0;
arr = [];
var startPoint = 0;
while (i <= jki) {
  i++;
  arr.push(str.slice(startPoint, str.slice((i * maxCount) - maxCount, i * maxCount).lastIndexOf(" ") - 1))
  startPoint = str.slice((i * maxCount) - maxCount, i * maxCount).lastIndexOf(" ");
}
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This way i get things like the first is good, second is empty ??, next is wrecked :-s :

```
[
  "Persons: Amy, bertha, Charlie, Donkey, Evy, Felicia, Ghunter, Hercules, Indica, Jody, Katy, Linsay",
  "",
  "say, Moony, Nigel, Opethry, Phil, Quinton, Ricial, Stefany, Trudy, Ursla, Vlinder, Wendy, Xion, Yvy, Zu"
]
```

**Edit**

What i looking for is that str is maximum 100 char in length and names are full written.

```
[
  "Persons: Amy, bertha, Charlie, Donkey, Evy, Felicia, Ghunter, Hercules, Indica, Jody, Katy, Linsay,",
  "Moony, Nigel, Opethry, Phil, Quinton, Ricial, Stefany, Trudy, Ursla, Vlinder, Wendy, Xion, Yvy, Zulu"
]
```

In this example `arr[0].length // 99` ,  `arr[1].length // 100`

If we would add a new name to list example `ZZ-top`

```
[
  "Persons: Amy, bertha, Charlie, Donkey, Evy, Felicia, Ghunter, Hercules, Indica, Jody, Katy, Linsay,",
  "Moony, Nigel, Opethry, Phil, Quinton, Ricial, Stefany, Trudy, Ursla, Vlinder, Wendy, Xion, Yvy,",
  "Zulu, ZZ-top"
]
```

In this example `arr[0].length // 99` ,  `arr[1].length // 95` , `arr[2].length // 12`

```
"Zulu," would made arr[2].length // 101 so moving over to next (as is variable maxCount = 100)
```

Can someone see what i am missing ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: So you're trying to splice the string whenever it is longer than 100 chars and/or if it sees a "specific char"? Which character? Do you want the next string to _start_ on that character or the old one to _end_ on that character?

Comment: @Mojtaba and how to know the limit parameter ?

Comment: @8protons this is my goal: arr = ["(str maxLen 100", "(str maxLen 100"], "(str maxLen 100", "(str maxLen 100" ] as example is str is 301-400 chars long

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs Yes but you wrote that you want the string to end on a specific character. Which specific character? The letter 'c'? A '?' sign?

Comment: @8protons so if see a char " " split but before maxCount

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs Is the specific char " or is it literally two chars like " "?

Comment: @8protons names must be fullwritten so end with , OR " "

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs One or two quotation marks? And if it sees this character, does the count reset?

Comment: Yes ideal looks like ´[
  "Persons: Amy, bertha, Charlie, Donkey, Evy, Felicia, Ghunter, Hercules, Indica, Jody, Katy, Linsay",
  "Linsay, Moony, Nigel, Opethry, Phil, Quinton, Ricial, Stefany, Trudy, Ursla, Vlinder, Wendy, Xion, Yvy, Zulu"
]

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs, limit can be maxCount

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs You have Linsay twice; in two arrays. Why?

Comment: I think you need to step back and really define your requirements

Comment: @8protons Linsay is mistake only once ^^

Comment: @8protons thanks anyway for your time

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs No problem at all, friend. I really would like to see you clean up this question and be _very specific_ about what you want. For example, tell us specifically, not just in code, your maximum length, what character(s) terminate the string array to start a new one, what to do when cutting a string in the middle of a name, etc. Then I'd gladly answer.

Comment: And provide an example string and what you'd like to see AFTER we run our little code.

Comment: @8protons done! hope it clear a little out, if you still looking to find the anwser :D Thanks for your time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113081/discussion-between-8protons-and-phil-andelhofs).

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs join me in chat. You still have unclear things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I took the time to actually make it work according to your criteria. All the steps are explained in the comments.

```js
var str = "Persons: Amy, bertha, Charlie, Donkey, Evy, Felicia, Ghunter, Hercules, Indica, Jody, Katy, Linsay, Moony, Nigel, Opethry, Phil, Quinton, Ricial, Stefany, Trudy, Ursla, Vlinder, Wendy, Xion, Yvy, Zulu";
var maxCount = 100;
var splitNames = function(str, max){
    // ["person:","Amy,","bertha,",...]
    var names = str.split(' '),
        lines = [],
        line = 0,
        lineLength = 0;

    // loop through our array of names
    names.forEach(function(name){
        // if length is more than our max
        if(lineLength + name.length + 1 > max){
            line += 1; // move to next line
            lineLength = 0; // reset length counter
        } else {
            lineLength += 1; // add 1 for the space we'll add later
        }
        // make sure we add an empty array if there isn't one
        lines[line] = lines[line] || [];
        
        // add the current name
        lines[line].push(name);
        
        // add name length to the line length
        lineLength += name.length;
    });
    
    return lines.map(function(line){
        // join our names with a space (which we counted toward the length)
        return line.join(' ');
    });
}
console.log(splitNames(str, maxCount));
```

Comment: First sight better than my own!

Comment: Thank you for your time! This is better!

Comment: No problem! It was a fun challenge :)

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you miss. Most important one is that you should start next slice from startPoint, not from (i * maxCount) - maxCount. Another biggie is that lastIndexOf will count from start of the slice, not from start of the original string (which will be less then maxCount and then less then startPoint for all slices except first one). This is why second chunk is empty. Combined with the first biggie, it makes last chunk to start from "say", as it starts from position of last space in previous chunk.

You should also take care about last chunk to not cut off by last space as there might be no spaces at the end. And also take care of slices that might have no spaces in them. Finally, number of chunks might not be Math.floor(str.length / maxCount) even if str.length / maxCount is exact integer.

To illustrate the point, I took freedom to fix it the way I see what you are trying to do.

```
var str = "Persons: Amy, bertha, Charlie, Donkey, Evy, Felicia, Ghunter, Hercules, Indica, Jody, Katy, Linsay, Moony, Nigel, Opethry, Phil, Quinton, Ricial, Stefany, Trudy, Ursla, Vlinder, Wendy, Xion, Yvy, Zulu";
var maxCount = 100;
var jki = Math.floor(str.length / maxCount);
var arr = [];
var startPoint = 0;
while (startPoint < str.length) {
    while (startPoint < str.length && str[startPoint] == ',' ||  str[startPoint] == ' ') // chop leading commas and spaces off
    startPoint++;
    var nextSlice;
    var nextStart;
    if (startPoint + maxCount >= str.length) {
        // last chunk goes in completely
        nextSlice = str.slice(startPoint);
        nextStart = str.length;
    }
    else {
        // not last, chop of by last space if any
        nextSlice = str.slice(startPoint, startPoint + maxCount);
        nextStart = nextSlice.lastIndexOf(" ");
        if (nextStart <= 0) {
            nextStart = nextSlice.length;
        }
        else {
            nextStart -= 1;
        }
        nextStart += startPoint; // adjust for slice starting not at the beginning of str
     }
     arr.push(str.slice(startPoint, nextStart));
     startPoint = nextStart + 1;
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: No worries! As  ShamSUP already noted, it was a fun challenge :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "Persons: Amy, bertha, Charlie, Donkey, Evy, Felicia, Ghunter, Hercules, Indica, Jody, Katy, Linsay, Moony, Nigel, Opethry, Phil, Quinton, Ricial, Stefany, Trudy, Ursla, Vlinder, Wendy, Xion, Yvy, Zulu";

var arr = str.split(' ').map(word => word.substr(0, 100)).reduce((acc, word) => {
  acc.length += word.length + 1;
  if (acc.length > 100) {
    acc.length = word.length - 1;
    acc.lines.push([word]);
  } else {
    acc.lines[acc.lines.length - 1].push(word);
  }
  return acc;
},{lines: [[]], length: -1}).lines.map(line => line.join(' '));

console.log(arr);
```