# How to create multidimensional array / array tree from list of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of:

```
["Lorem", "Ipsum", "Colo", "sit", "ame", "consecteur"]
```

The task is to make array within an array for combined 10 character length which in this case would be something like this:

```
[
  ["Lorem", "Ipsum"],
  ["Colo", "sit", "ame"], 
  ["consecteur"]
]
```

I tried to do this:

```
var arr = ["Lorem", "Ipsum", "Colo", "sit", "ame", "consecteur"];
var combArr = [];
var charCount = 0;

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    charCount += arr[i].length;
    if (charCount <= 10) {
        combArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
    if (charCount > 10 && charCount <= 20) {
        combArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
    // ...
}
```

But then it will push it back to the same order as before since I am only pushing each iteration that passed the condition. I have no clue as to how to make the multidimensional array as above. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Pretty similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470910/break-long-string-at-specif-char-and-max-length-js - just remove the specific char requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a corrected version of your code:

```
var arr = ["Lorem", "Ipsum", "Colo", "sit", "ame", "consecteur"];
var combArr = [];
var charCount = 0;
var currArr = []; // ADDED: the current list of words 

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (charCount && (charCount + arr[i].length > 10)) {
        // save list
        combArr.push(currArr);
        // ... and start new list
        currArr = [];
        charCount = 0;
     }
     charCount += arr[i].length;
     currArr.push(arr[i]);
}   
// finally add remaining list to result:
combArr.push(currArr);
```

Comment: Creates an empty row for `["12345678901", "2"]`

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you're missing;  You need to create *new* arrays, and then push those multiple arrays into a parent array.

An example, to get you going;

```
var container = [];
var child1 = [];
var child2 = [];

child1.push("foo");
child1.push("bar");

child2.push("baz");

container.push(child1);
container.push(child2);

console.log(container); // [["foo", "bar"], ["baz"]]
```

I'll leave the conditional logic of the problem at hand to you, but this should get you past that hurdle.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this; (edited)

```js
 var arr = ["1234567890","hidden","para","meter"];
    var results= [];
    var charCount = 0;
    var temp=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      charCount += arr[i].length;
        if(charCount>10){
          results.push(temp);
          charCount=arr[i].length;
          temp=[arr[i]];
        }else{
          temp.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    if(temp.length){results.push(temp);}
    document.write(JSON.stringify(results))
```

Try this;

```js
var arr = ["Lorem", "Ipsum", "Colo", "sit", "ame", "consecteur"];
var results= [];
var charCount = 0;

for (var i = 0,temp=[]; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if((charCount += arr[i].length)>=10){
      temp.push(arr[i]);
      results.push(temp);
      charCount=0;
      temp=[];
    }else{
      temp.push(arr[i]);
    }
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(results))
```

Comment: Fails for `["1234567890", "hidden"];`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like this.

```js
var arr = ["Lorem", "Ipsum", "Colo", "sit", "ame", "consecteur"];
var MAX_LENGTH = 10;
var finalArray = arr.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  if (prev.length === 0) {
    prev.push([curr]);
  } else {
    var currentItemLength = prev[prev.length-1].reduce(function(iprev, icurr) {
      return iprev + icurr.length;
    }, 0);
    if (currentItemLength + curr.length > MAX_LENGTH) {
      prev.push([curr]);
    } else {
      prev[prev.length-1].push(curr);
    }
  }
  return prev;
}, []);
console.log(finalArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your code by adding one more level of nesting to your `combArr`, resetting your `charCount` for each new 'row' and handling the case when the first entry of `arr` is longer than 10 characters by appending `|| i == 0` to your if-condition:

```js
var arr = ["Lorem", "Ipsum", "Colo", "sit", "ame", "consecteur"];
var combArr = [[]];
var charCount = 0;

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    charCount += arr[i].length;
    if (charCount <= 10 || i == 0) {
        combArr[combArr.length-1].push(arr[i]);
    } else {
        charCount = arr[i].length;
        combArr.push([arr[i]]);
    }
}

console.log(combArr);
```

A more performant solution is:

```js
function format(array, chars) {
  var result = [], chars = 0, prev = 0, length = array.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    chars += array[i].length;
    if (i && chars > 10) {
      result.push(array.slice(prev, i));
      chars = array[i].length;
      prev = i;
    }
  }
  result.push(array.slice(prev, length));
  return result;
}

console.log(format(["Lorem", "Ipsum", "Colo", "sit", "ame", "consecteur"]));
console.log(format(["12345678901", "", "1234567890", "", "1"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not cater for:

1. The input array not being in the correct order, so as to ensure a complete pairing of 10 characters, for example it will not work with an input array of ["hello", "whatever"].
2. It does not cater for the conditional splitting of an array item into two separate arrays. 
   For Example ["hello", "whatever"] = [["hello", "whate"],["ver"]]

So with the information supplied you can try this:

```
var inputArray = ["Lorem", "Ipsum", "Colo", "sit", "ame", "consecteur"];
    var tempArray = [];
    var finalArray = [];
    var charCount = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {

        if ((charCount + inputArray[i].length) <= 10) {

            charCount += inputArray[i].length;

            tempArray.push(inputArray[i]);

            if (charCount == 10) {
                finalArray.push(tempArray);
                tempArray = [];
                charCount = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    //push whatever remains is in tempArray to the final array.
    if (tempArray.length)
        finalArray.push(tempArray);

    document.write(JSON.stringify(finalArray))
```